# How to get the i value and perform click action?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, get

[.get(i) is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZlD2.png)

```
List<WebElement> prdct = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h4[@class = 'product-name']"));
    WebElement addto = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@test() = 'ADD TO CART']"));
    for (int i = 0; i < prdct.size(); i++) {

        String Name = prdct.get(i).getText();
        System.out.println(Name);
        if (Name.contains("Pomegranate")) 
        {
            addto.get
            break;
        }

    }
```

I need to get the i index and perform click action but get() is working, please check the enclosed image for better understanding.

How to proceed with this?

Answer (score 0):

From your posted code it seems you should do the get(i) on `prdct` that is the list of elements if you have to perform an action with that element.

The `addto` seems to be an 'ADD TO CART' button and there is only one, you can perform the action in it as well but it's not a list so there is no possibility to use get in it.

In code, you probably want `prdct.get(i).click()`. And maybe after that `addto.click()`.

Comment: Thanks, i chose element instead of elements.... took me while but i figured it out.. Thanks for the help

Comment: You could mark the answer as correct if you consider it is

Answer (score 0):

`addto` is not a `List` but a `WebElement`, hence you cannot use `get(i)` (`WebElement` interface does not extend `List`).

Comment: i chose element instead of elements, Thanks